# Running multiple workers using Celery

Tags: python, celery

I need to read from Rabbitmq and execute task in parallel using Celery in a single system.

```
[2014-12-30 15:54:22,374: INFO/Worker-1] ...   
[2014-12-30 15:54:23,401: INFO/Worker-1] ...
[2014-12-30 15:54:30,878: INFO/Worker-1] ...
[2014-12-30 15:54:32,209: INFO/Worker-1] ...
[2014-12-30 15:54:33,255: INFO/Worker-1] ...
[2014-12-30 15:54:48,445: INFO/Worker-1] ...
[2014-12-30 15:54:49,811: INFO/Worker-1] ...
[2014-12-30 15:54:50,903: INFO/Worker-1] ...
[2014-12-30 15:55:39,674: INFO/Worker-1] ...
[2014-12-30 15:55:41,024: INFO/Worker-1] ...
[2014-12-30 15:55:42,147: INFO/Worker-1] ...
```

It seams only 1 worker is running all the time .. ie one after another in sequential order.
How can I configure Celery to run multiple workers to run parallel ?

Answer (score 25):

I have now updated my answer following the comment from MartinP regarding worker spawning child processes not threads:

Celery `worker` and `worker processes` are different things ([Read this for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31898311/celery-difference-between-concurrency-workers-and-autoscaling)).

When a worker is started it then spawns a certain number of child processes.

The default number of those processes is equal to a number of cores on that machine.

On Linux you can check the number of cores via:

```
$ nproc --all
```

Otherwise you can specify it yourself, for e.g.:

```
$ celery -A proj worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=2
```

In the above example there's one worker which will be able to spawn 2 child processes. It is normally advised to run a single worker per machine and the concurrency value will define how many processes will run in parallel, but if multiple workers required to run then you can start them like shown below:

```
$ celery -A proj worker -l info --concurrency=4 -n wkr1@hostname
$ celery -A proj worker -l info --concurrency=2 -n wkr2@hostname
$ celery -A proj worker -l info --concurrency=2 -n wkr3@hostname
```

Refer to celery [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html) for more info

Comment: concurency parameter does't run threads. It run child processes by default so it process tasks in parallel - http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-c

Comment: How do the concurrency and threads relate each other, if the default concurrency is the number of cores of the machine, what will be the number of threads? Is it configurable?

Comment: @ThomasJohn I _think_ the default number for threads is still the number of cores of the machine. Generally, you'll want to set the --concurrency flag high for thread-based workers.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your worker is just running a single process/thread.  You probably just need to add the [`--concurrency` or `-c` argument](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency) when starting the worker to spawn multiple (parallel) worker instances.

```
celery -A proj worker -c 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html?highlight=parallel

You can look for **Canvas primitives** there you can see how to make groups for parallel execution.

> class celery.group(task1[, task2[, task3[, … taskN]]]) Creates a group
>   of tasks to be executed in parallel.

Otherwise a good way is to go to the IRC channel and ask that special questions. Normally there are people who know that very good and they can help you.